# Which .NET Development Controls/Tools suite do you think can be worth to pay for

Tags: .net, controls

I'm thinking on purchase a Control suite to meet some specific client needs in a WPF LOB Application. I also have application SilverLight, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC

Any Advise on that? I consider evaluate Telerik, DevExpress, ComponentOne, Infragistics.

I want to pay less money but get the more benefits that I can afford.

Thanks

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used Telerik, DevExpress and Infragistcs I would say there isn't one that meets all my needs. Sure, they all have about the same components (grids, tabs, "user control du jour") but controls perform better than others within each suite. You really need to evaluate the specific problem you trying to solve and see which control from which vendor works best.

Comment: ok at this moment my problem is to have a Reporting Tool capable of generate Bills for about 400 Items (Multi page), but if I'm going to invest in that I was thinking on get a full suite for other needs in the future

Answer (score 0):

you already mentioned all good vendors.

But i would say that you must evaluate grid controls form all of the vendors because grid control is one of the control which is heavy used and there are significant performance differences between vendors

Answer (score 0):

My experience with purchased controls (and I have quite a bit, including WeOnlyDo, Infragistics, Telerik, Dart, and others) is that they're buggy, poorly implemented, poorly supported, and produced primarily to showcase impressive demonstrations. When actually used in real software they're difficult to work with, and demonstrate only poor production values.

In short, in my opinion (and this is only my opinion), they're a crutch for the weak, and not worth the time, money, or effort required to deal with them.

You should think VERY hard about what you're doing and why it can't be done with standard controls. Remember, users know how to use the standard controls, they're comfortable with them. When you get into fancy non-standard stuff that deviates from the [standard guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you just end up wasting effort and confusing users. You need to have a VERY VERY good reason whenever you deviate from that.

Comment: Yes in my experience I have seen that too, though I need to work more with RAD and that includes not having time to re invent the wheel doing all controls by myself

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience **DevExpress** is high memory consumer, for some web project we had to change all controls from such toolkit for Microsoft ones because performance issues, by doing a memory analysis we prove such fact. It is also important to say that it is completely object oriented which is comfortable for developers I prefer its usage for **Desktop based Applications**.

https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Purchase/